# JavaScript to enable new HTML5 button attributes: formaction, formmethod

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modernizr, webshim

I need to have different buttons in a form that submit the data to different actions. I could do this with the new HTML5 attributes of button formaction and formmethod: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button

But those of course do not work in older versions of Internet Explorer. Is anybody aware of some javascript that conditionally adds event handlers to buttons in older browsers to simulate the above behaviour?

I've seen the list at https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills but did not see such a library there.

Comment: I might have found the answer in a link suggested by SO: http://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/demos/webforms.html I'll test it next week.

Comment: Yes webshims has implented this feature. For all unsupporting browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest would most likely be to do it the old fashioned way and preventDefault on the form (on submit) and do what you want to do, based on any condition you may have.

Polyfilling the native functions although would be preferable would most likely be a time loss in the project